# Dropzone form elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I have implemented DropzoneJS for purpose of galery. I have to add more fields: Name of galery, submit...

I have this code:

```
<script src="assets/libs/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/dropzone/dropzone.css">

<form id="form" action="assets/libs/dropzone/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Galery name*"/> <br/>
<div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
</div>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How to proccess selected images with jQuery(Ajax), how to send it to php script:  `$("input[name=file]").val()` -> doesn't work, expected.

**EDIT**:   I need only name of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".fileInput" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log(  "file name: " + $( this ).val() );
});
```

should work fine within loop for multiple fields.

About sending file to server via Ajax is different problem.
Here is a great example which suits your needs( [Ajax/Jquery - PHP )](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/)